# Show commits on local branch A that local branch B has not

Tags: git, branch, commit, difference

I've already read that there is

```sh
$ git checkout B
$ git cherry -v A
```

but this produces nothing for me and I suppose that this (and some other similar command, I think `git log B ^A`, which does actually output some differences, but somehow did not show all the different commits) only applies for the case of B being the remote tracking branch of A.

But I want to compare two local branches' commits, so how do I do this?

Update:
To be more verbose, I tried

```sh
git log B..A
```

and

```sh
git log B ^A
```

but `HEAD` from A did not show up, although it wasn't on B.

EDIT: Not sure anymore, if I did the `git cherry` the wrong way around, I probably made a mistake, so it should actually work

Comment: `git cherry` is specifically for handling commits that have, or have not, been copied via `git cherry-pick`. Given the simpler question in your subject line, `git log B..A` *is* what you want. If it's not what you want, you might need to read up on how Git's commit graph works. Note that `git log B ^A` means `git log A..B`; `git log B..A` can be spelled `git log A ^B`. The one in front of the two dots is negated; the one at the end is a positive reference.

Comment: If you *are* interested in commits that are, or may have been, copied to different commits, with different hash IDs, but which have the same *effect* as their source commits, then `git cherry-pick` is a useful tool. To properly describe it, you'll need to know how the commit graph works. (You will find that this is a theme in Git: to use it, you need to understand the graph.)

Comment: For (much) more about how the graph works—the fundamental building blocks for all of this stuff, including `git merge` too—see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show all commits reachable from A, but exclude those reachable from B:

```
git log A ^B # read: A, but *not* B
```

or, more in line with the general usage of git log:

```
git log B..A # read: show history from B to A
```

Behavior of both commands is identical (both refspecs describe the same commits)

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that (just fixed the typo in my answer indicating I tried it)

Comment: I'm confused by your comment in your edited question. You say "head from A did not show up, although it wasn't on B". That's expected, you specify all commits in B, but not on A

Comment: Args. Now I see. I got it inverted. But since A and B are just arbitrary placeholders, it shouldn't really matter. I'll update my answer nevertheless to swap A and B

Comment: You're right, and I either misread or my source for the `git cherry` command was the wrong way around, too. The `git log B..A` is relatable, because one can remember it easily as 'what commits do I need to go from B to A'. Not sure why they thought the `git log` syntax was good or necessary.

Comment: @polynomial_donut I don't understand your rant. The syntax (offically called a "refspec") is necessary so that you can specify ranges of commits to show. How else would you tell Git which commits you want to see/operate on?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose to run:

```
git branch
```

and to get `branchA` and `branchB`

We can compare them with:

```
git diff branchA..branchB
```

Order is not really important, if you reverse branchB and branchA the plus signs become minus signs and viceversa. Generally the older branch goes first but it's just a convention

```
git diff --color-words branchA..branchB
```

With this command you just have a different view of the results got with the previous command

You can even compare in the following ways to select the ancestors of the last commit in branchB:

```
git diff branchA..branchB^
git diff branchA..branchB^^
```

Comment: `git diff`, used this way, compares the *snapshots* in the two commits `branchA` and `branchB`. This is very different from `git log`, which when used with `branchA..branchB`, starts by showing you the commit (complete with hash ID and log message) from the tip of `branchB`, then shows its parent(s), then their parent(s), and so on, until it reaches any commits reachable from `branchA`, which it does not show.

Comment: @torek: yes, I thought from the OP's "I want to compare two local branches' commits" that he was searching exactly this kind of comparison